Multiple Reads cannot Goes to ALignment process
I am working on a Multi-strain variant analysis Pipeline. I have been encountering an error for the past few weeks. Firstly, when I use the Combine operator in my Workflow, I get an error message saying 'Only one read is running all the steps' despite providing two reads, and I only get one output. Secondly, when I replaced the Combine operator with the Cross operator, the workflow stops after two steps. I want to have multi-strain as input and get output for each strain in all the steps
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.ref = ''    
params.reads = []
params.snpEff_db = 'Pseudomonas_aeruginosa'

def getFastqList() {
    def input = System.console().readLine('Enter fastq filenames separated by spaces: ')
    def inputList = input.split(' ') as List
    def fullPathList = inputList.collect { file(it).toAbsolutePath().toString() }
    return fullPathList
}
process indexReference {
    tag "INDEX:${params.ref}"

    input:
        path ref

    publishDir './ref_index/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        path "${ref}*", emit: ref_index

    script:
        """
        bwa index $ref
        samtools faidx $ref
        """
}

process trimReads {
    tag "FASTP:${sampleid}"

    input:
        tuple val(sampleid), path(reads)

    publishDir './trimtry/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        tuple val(sampleid), path("${sampleid}_trimmed.fastq.gz")  

    script:
        """
        fastp -i ${reads} -o ${sampleid}_trimmed.fastq.gz
        """
}

process alignReads {
    tag "BWA:${sampleid}"

    input:
        tuple val(sampleid), path(trimmed_reads), path(ref_index)

    publishDir './aligntry/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        path "${sampleid}.bam", emit: aligned_bam

    script:
        """
        bwa mem ${params.ref} ${trimmed_reads} > ${sampleid}.sam
        samtools view -Sb ${sampleid}.sam > ${sampleid}.bam
        """
}
process sortBam {
    tag "SORT:${sampleid}"

    input:
        tuple val(sampleid), path(aligned_bam)

    publishDir './sorted_bam/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        path "${sampleid}_sorted.bam", emit: sorted_bam

    script:
        """
        samtools sort -o ${sampleid}_sorted.bam ${aligned_bam}
        """
}

workflow {
    def reads = getFastqList()

    if (params.ref && reads) {
        println "Reference genome: ${params.ref}"
        println "Input reads: ${reads}"

        channel
            .fromPath(params.ref)
            | indexReference
            | set { ref_index }

        channel
            .from(reads)
            .map { file -> tuple(new File(file).getName().split('\\.')[0], file) }
            | trimReads
            | set { trim }
            
        trim
            .combine (ref_index)
            | alignReads
            |set {aligned}


        aligned
            .aligned_bam
            | map { bam -> tuple('aligned_bam', bam.toString()) }
            | sortBam
            | set { sorted }

        sorted
            .sorted_bam
            | map { bam -> tuple('sorted_bam', bam.toString()) }
            | removeDuplicates
            | set { dedup }

        dedup
            .dedup_bam
            | map { bam -> tuple('dedup_bam', bam.toString()) }
            | callVariants
            | set { variants }

        variants
            .vcf
            | map { vcf -> tuple(vcf.getName().split('\\.')[0], vcf) }
            | annotateVariants
            | set { annotated }

        annotated
            .annotated_vcf
            | map { vcf -> tuple(vcf.getName().split('\\.')[0], vcf) }
            | filterSNPs
            | set { filtered_snps }

        filtered_snps
            .view()
    } else {
        error "Please provide valid paths for the reference genome and input reads."
    }
}

Error:
(base) virudhagiri@virudhagiri-HP-Laptop-15s-eq2xxx:~/Desktop/ngs/helo$ nextflow run try14.nf --ref /home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/sequence2.fasta

N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.04.4
Launching try14.nf [stupefied_goldwasser] DSL2 - revision: 35d5b5e299
Enter fastq filenames separated by spaces: ERR010476.fastq SRR30404095.fastq
Reference genome: /home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/sequence2.fasta
Input reads: [/home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/helo/ERR010476.fastq, /home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/helo/SRR30404095.fastq]
executor >  local (7)
[86/f08640] process > indexReference (INDEX:/home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/sequence2.fasta) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[5f/848891] process > trimReads (FASTP:SRR30404095)                                        [ 50%] 1 of 2
executor >  local (8)
[86/f08640] process > indexReference (INDEX:/home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/sequence2.fasta) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[5f/848891] process > trimReads (FASTP:SRR30404095)                                        [ 50%] 1 of 2
executor >  local (9)
[86/f08640] process > indexReference (INDEX:/home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/sequence2.fasta) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[5f/848891] process > trimReads (FASTP:SRR30404095)                                        [ 50%] 1 of 2
executor >  local (10)
[86/f08640] process > indexReference (INDEX:/home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/sequence2.fasta) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[eb/b4db34] process > trimReads (FASTP:ERR010476)                                          [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
executor >  local (15)
[86/f08640] process > indexReference (INDEX:/home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/sequence2.fasta) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[eb/b4db34] process > trimReads (FASTP:ERR010476)                                          [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[ef/5037a0] process > alignReads (BWA:ERR010476)                                           [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[b7/f19097] process > sortBam (SORT:aligned_bam)                                           [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[a8/47177c] process > removeDuplicates (DEDUP:sorted_bam)                                  [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[e3/380746] process > callVariants (BCFTOOLS:dedup_bam)                                    [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[a8/6680b8] process > annotateVariants (SNPEFF:dedup_bam)                                  [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[2e/1a508e] process > filterSNPs (FILTER:dedup_bam_annotated)                              [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
/home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/helo/work/2e/1a508e96d2bcd5c32dcbf2fdce8756/dedup_bam_annotated_filtered_snps.vcf
Completed at: 14-Oct-2024 14:13:53
Duration    : 2m 25s
CPU hours   : (a few seconds)
Succeeded   : 15

While Using Cross operator
The code:
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.ref = ''    
params.reads = []
params.snpEff_db = 'Pseudomonas_aeruginosa'

def getFastqList() {
    def input = System.console().readLine('Enter fastq filenames separated by spaces: ')
    def inputList = input.split(' ') as List
    def fullPathList = inputList.collect { file(it).toAbsolutePath().toString() }
    return fullPathList
}
process indexReference {
    tag "INDEX:${params.ref}"

    input:
        path ref

    publishDir './ref_index/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        path "${ref}*", emit: ref_index

    script:
        """
        bwa index $ref
        samtools faidx $ref
        """
}

process trimReads {
    tag "FASTP:${sampleid}"

    input:
        tuple val(sampleid), path(reads)

    publishDir './trimtry/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        tuple val(sampleid), path("${sampleid}_trimmed.fastq.gz")  

    script:
        """
        fastp -i ${reads} -o ${sampleid}_trimmed.fastq.gz
        """
}

process alignReads {
    tag "BWA:${sampleid}"

    input:
        tuple val(sampleid), path(trimmed_reads), path(ref_index)

    publishDir './aligntry/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        path "${sampleid}.bam", emit: aligned_bam

    script:
        """
        bwa mem ${params.ref} ${trimmed_reads} > ${sampleid}.sam
        samtools view -Sb ${sampleid}.sam > ${sampleid}.bam
        """
}
process sortBam {
    tag "SORT:${sampleid}"

    input:
        tuple val(sampleid), path(aligned_bam)

    publishDir './sorted_bam/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        path "${sampleid}_sorted.bam", emit: sorted_bam

    script:
        """
        samtools sort -o ${sampleid}_sorted.bam ${aligned_bam}
        """
}

workflow {
    def reads = getFastqList()

    if (params.ref && reads) {
        println "Reference genome: ${params.ref}"
        println "Input reads: ${reads}"

        channel
            .fromPath(params.ref)
            | indexReference
            | set { ref_index }

        channel
            .from(reads)
            .map { file -> tuple(new File(file).getName().split('\\.')[0], file) }
            | trimReads
            | set { trim }
            
        trim
            .cross (ref_index)
            | alignReads
            |set {aligned}


        aligned
            .aligned_bam
            | map { bam -> tuple('aligned_bam', bam.toString()) }
            | sortBam
            | set { sorted }

        sorted
            .sorted_bam
            | map { bam -> tuple('sorted_bam', bam.toString()) }
            | removeDuplicates
            | set { dedup }

        dedup
            .dedup_bam
            | map { bam -> tuple('dedup_bam', bam.toString()) }
            | callVariants
            | set { variants }

        variants
            .vcf
            | map { vcf -> tuple(vcf.getName().split('\\.')[0], vcf) }
            | annotateVariants
            | set { annotated }

        annotated
            .annotated_vcf
            | map { vcf -> tuple(vcf.getName().split('\\.')[0], vcf) }
            | filterSNPs
            | set { filtered_snps }

        filtered_snps
            .view()
    } else {
        error "Please provide valid paths for the reference genome and input reads."
    }
}

Error:
(base) virudhagiri@virudhagiri-HP-Laptop-15s-eq2xxx:~/Desktop/ngs/helo$ nextflow run loop.nf --ref /home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/helo/sequence2.fasta
N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.04.4
Launching loop.nf [drunk_gutenberg] DSL2 - revision: d43dba08a0
Enter fastq filenames separated by spaces: ERR010476.fastq SRR30404095.fastq
Reference genome: /home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/helo/sequence2.fasta
Input reads: [/home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/helo/ERR010476.fastq, /home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/helo/SRR30404095.fastq]
executor >  local (3)
[60/0cf263] process > indexReference (INDEX:/home/virudhagiri/Desktop/ngs/helo/sequence2.fasta) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[a6/be4ead] process > trimReads (FASTP:ERR010476)                                               [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
[-        ] process > alignReads                                                                -
[-        ] process > sortBam                                                                   -
[-        ] process > removeDuplicates                                                          -
[-        ] process > callVariants                                                              -
[-        ] process > annotateVariants                                                          -
[-        ] process > filterSNPs                                                                -

I want multiple ot[ut for each strain.

You don't need to use combine or cross to add the reference index in a process. I think what's happening is you are trying to mix channels with different number of elements, and nextflow stops once the first channel is exhausted. I thought this behaviour was changed with DSL2, but maybe that's just in process inputs where any channels can now be used multiple times.
process alignReads {
    tag "BWA:${sampleid}"

    input:
        tuple val(sampleid), path(trimmed_reads)
        path(ref_index)

    publishDir './aligntry/', mode: 'copy'

    output:
        path "${sampleid}.bam", emit: aligned_bam

    script:
        """
        bwa mem ${params.ref} ${trimmed_reads} > ${sampleid}.sam
        samtools view -Sb ${sampleid}.sam > ${sampleid}.bam
        """
}

If you split the input declaration so the ref_index is separate, it can be used by a process any number of times in DSL2.
I use a different layout in my workflow declarations, so I would write this instead (untested):
workflow {
    def reads = getFastqList()
    if (params.ref && reads) {
        println "Reference genome: ${params.ref}"
        println "Input reads: ${reads}"

        channel
            .fromPath(params.ref)
            .set { reference }
        channel
            .from(reads)
            .map { file -> tuple(new File(file).getName().split('\\.')[0], file) }
            .set { raw_reads }

        indexReference( reference )
        trimReads( raw_reads )
        alignReads( trimReads.out, indexReference.out.ref_index )
...

As an aside, the getFastqList function seems a little overkill. Channel creation with fromPath and a directory with a glob for all fastqs like Channel.fromPath("${params.inDir}/*fastq") will automatically identify all relevant files in a directory, so unless you specifically want control of which file names by typing them out, this is a more useful solution.

Now only i saw that before align step..trim also couldn't trim multi reads inputs but it trim only one input..others trimmed reads output files are empty so that align step only align first one which has trimmed data...other reads are run but it has empty output file which has zero data..

Now only i saw that before align step..trim also couldn't trim multi reads inputs but it trim only one input..others trimmed reads output files are empty so that align step only align first one which has trimmed data...other reads are run but it has empty output file which has zero data..Next that one output file has low number of output data which i was cross checked by galaxy most of the genes are missing in starting alignment output filke onwards.....and also it shows chromosome error like that after annotation it didnt has transcrip id,protein id etc,.. so i have 3 problem in this pipeline

Did you do any testing before you built the entire workflow? I usually test each process individually, then iteratively add others until I get to the full pipeline.

yeah i did index trim after align individualy

Yes, I did the indexing, trimming, and alignment steps individually. After that, I combined these three steps, but the indexing only worked properly. The trimming step did not produce the correct output for multiple reads in the subsequent steps. It processes one read and gives an output for that one, but the workflow result shows that multiple reads were run, like 3 out of 3. However, only one read produces an output, and the outputs for the other reads are empty
